# MD5 é bom o suficiente?

Tags: sql, postgresql, md5, distinct

Estou trabalhando em um sistema legado, que têm um banco de dados com uns 5 anos de registros acumulados sem nenhuma normalização. Entre outras coisas, sua finalidade é permitir que os usuários escrevam e publiquem postagens no mesmo estilo do Twitter, mas sem a limitação de 140 caracteres. Alguns usuários estão reclamando que suas postagens estão aparecendo várias vezes. O sistema estava com um sério problema no momento em que as postagens eram cadastradas, fazendo com que o mesmo conteúdo fosse inserido várias vezes.

A nível de sistema consegui corrigir o problema, mas agora tenho uma tabela gigantesca de posts, sendo que muitos dos registros têm 2... 3... até 6 cópias. O correto seria remover as duplicações, mas em um primeiro momento, o que quero fazer é simplesmente selecionar um *post* de cada.

Para ilustrar:

[image: Atualmente está assim]

Podemos notar que os registros 1 e 2 são do mesmo usuário, e possuem exatamente o mesmo corpo.

A única coluna que pode identificar que um *post* é igual ao outro com 100% de certeza é o `corpo`, que é do tipo `TEXT`. Diferentemente do exemplo (que foi apenas para ilustrar), esta coluna pode facilmente ter seus 1000 caracteres, então usar `SELECT DISTINCT ON (body) * FROM posts;` não me parece uma ideia das mais geniais.

Então o que eu pensei foi em criar um `STORED PROCEDURE` para gerar o MD5 do corpo de todos os posts, que seria armazenado em um campo indexado. Então eu poderia fazer o `SELECT DISTINCT` baseado neste *hash* MD5.

A tabela então ficaria assim:

[image: Tabela após a alteração]

Com o `body_hash` sendo um campo indexado, eu poderia fazer algo como

`SELECT DISTINCT ON(body_hash) * FROM posts;`

Estou em dúvida porque esta tabela tem milhões de registros. MD5 é bom o suficiente para a minha situação? Ou há algo melhor que eu possa fazer para selecionar somente um registro de cada?

Comment: Você quer criptografa o campo ou criar  uma chave única para ele?

Comment: Esta coluna `corpo` é sua chave primária? Dê mais detalhes do objetivo disto.

Comment: Não @bigown. É o banco de dados de uma aplicação Ruby on Rails, então a chave primária é o ID.

Comment: @PedroVinícius pelo menos já sabemos que tem uma outra coluna que é 100% confiável que é diferente. Ela não te serve? O MD5 pode ser útil, dependendo da necessidade, a pergunta não deixa isto claro. Por que precisa saber a diferença? Vai usar isto uma vez (ou bem, eventual) para resolver os problema, ou será algo que ficará na aplicação?

Comment: @bigown, mesmo que o corpo dos posts sejam iguais, o ID sempre será diferente. No caso o que eu quero fazer por enquanto é ignorar os posts repetidos, e para identificar a repetição, o único campo que eu consigo ver é o corpo :/

Comment: @PedroVinícius ainda tem uma coisa esquisita no texto. Esta coluna sempre é diferente? Ou ela **pode** ser diferente? Você quer usá-la para descobrir qual linha é diferente sem olhar as outras colunas?

Comment: @bigown, vou detalhar mais o texto.

Comment: @bigown, melhorei a descrição lá.

Comment: Então você vai fazer isto só uma vez para resolver o problema passado?

Comment: Simples,md5 não é bom o suficiente para querer se proteger informações.Caso você só queira comparar informações,então tudo bem,mas caso queira proteger as informações,então não.Ele é somente mão única,criptografa a informação mas não descriptografa.Você teria que fazer outros meios para pegar de volta esta criptografia do md5. Não aconselho a trabalhar com md5,já tive experiência com esta função e não me ajudou muito.

Comment: @bigown, sim, minha idéia é gerar o MD5 para todas as linhas somente uma vez, já que a nível de sistema (no método de criação de posts), o problema foi corrigido.

Comment: @Falion, o meu caso não tem a ver com proteger os dados. É só pra gerar uma versão mais compacta do texto e usar no SELECT DISTINCT. Penso que seja mais 'leve' que fazer o mesmo procedimento em cima do campo corpo.

Comment: Se você não deseja remover as duplicações fisicamente, você pode removê-las logicamente. Crie um campo que vai agir como flag (algo como deleted ou disabled). Se o valor estiver true, este registro está desabilitado ou deletado. Na consulta que retorna os posts, você ignora os registros desabilitados. Para marcar os desabilitados a estratégia do MD5 não é ruim (no SQL Server uso o CHECKSUM para esses casos). Lembrando que mesmo que seja demorado (pela quantidade de registros), você fará isso uma vez só, já que você corrigiu o sistema para não duplicar registros.

Comment: Posso estar falando besteira, mas não seria mais eficiente checar o corpo e o ID e ainda um time como um limite de 30 segundos, para até detectar possiveis tentativas de SPAM? Eu entendo que uma hash poderia resolver, mas dependendo de como gerou a hash vai ser o mesmo que fazer nada (hipotéticamente), não sei se entendi o caso, mas quero dizer se usar errado vai só ter mais trabalho para resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O MD5-Message Digest 5 é um algoritmo Hash.

Algoritmos Hash tem como objetivo manter a integridade dos dados e funcionam mais ou menos assim:

Tem-se uma entrada M, uma função Hash H e uma saída (código hash) H(M).

M->H->H(M)

Um algoritmo Hash é considerado seguro se entradas diferentes resultarem em saídas diferentes, ou seja, se mudar um bit, a saída deve ser totalmente diferente.

O algoritmo MD5 há algum anos atrás era seguro, mas hoje há algoritmo melhores.

O ponto fraco no algoritmo MD5 está na saída hash gerada, que é de 128 bits, por ser pequena, pode gerar conflitos, ou seja, entradas diferentes podem gerar saídas iguais, portanto quebrando a segurança do algoritmo.

Qual a alternativa ao MD5?

Existem várias alternativas, mas uma das mais conhecidas é o algoritmo SHA-2 Family.

É mais seguro que o MD5. O código hash (saída) gerado tem um intervalo maior, podendo ser de 224, 256, 512 etc bits, com o código maior mais difícil é entradas diferentes gerarem saídas iguais.

Conclusão

Acho que pode ser uma solução para o seu problema.

Answer (score 3):

## Confiabilidade do MD5 como único

Se pretende confiar 100% no [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities) para descobrir se é igual, saiba que não dá para confiar. O MD5 pode ser uma base para já ter certeza que é diferente, ele é confiável quando é diferente. Mas dois códigos MD5 podem ser iguais para conteúdos diferentes.

Eu diria que o MD5 tem bem mais de 99,99999999% de chance de dar certo, mas não 100%. Se é um cadastro cheio de problemas, ele resolverá tudo, ou em situação bem excepcional, deixará passar alguma coisa, o que já é um ganho expressivo. Mas se for só para arrumar o problema uma vez e não será útil para outras coisas, o custo de gerar o MD5 nem compensa o esforço. Gerar um código MD5 é "caro".

## Solução real

Indexe a coluna de texto mesmo, resolva o problema e apague esse índice. É mais fácil e mais confiável.

Vai acabar gerando falsos positivos com isso. E se o usuário quis postar a mesma mensagem mais de uma vez? Apagará uma mensagem legítima. E olha que estou considerando que neste `DISTINCT` o identificador do usuário será considerado.

## Se pretende evitar novos duplicados

Isto é mais hipotético, não parece ser o caso.

Se pretende evitar que novas colunas sejam repetidas até pode fazer isso para ganhar tempo. Mas se achar um repetido tem que verificar o texto completo para ter certeza que não houve colisão. Essa verificação na prática quase nunca ocorrerá, afinal quase 100% das vezes o `SELECT` retornará 0 linhas distintas e não precisará fazer mais nada, mesmo nestes caso, será rápido verificar as que retornarem, se tudo estiver certo só retornará uma linha. Então pode ser eficiente. Eu não usaria assim.

Na verdade usar o campo texto será bem razoavelmente eficiente em processamento também. Não em espaço ocupado pelo índice e o tempo gasto no seu acesso. Pode causar estrago no cache. Esse é o real problema de usar a coluna muito grande.

Mas entenda que qualquer inserção ou atualização de dados dessa coluna será consideravelmente mais lenta por causa do MD5. Mas não quer dizer que seja um problema. Faça um teste se pode arcar com este custo.

Tem um truque que pode ajudar, mas não sei se é o caso, de qualquer forma não garantirá o 100%. Indexe o *hash* junto com um pequeno trecho do texto. Pode ser o(s) primeiro(s) caractere(s), ou outro trecho que seja mais propenso a ser diferente, mas precisa ser um trecho que seja garantido que esteja presente em todos textos para ser útil. É bem mais raro dar colisão em textos com trechos iguais. Isso só melhora a chance. E aumentará o consumo de espaço, então a utilidade é questionável.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).