# É seguro usar session_id com MD5?

Tags: php, md5

Estou pegando a session_id e colocando ela com criptografia MD5, pra fazer um processo de logout.

Gostaria de saber se tem algum problema de segurança nisso, desse modo que to fazendo, ou corro algum risco futuramente?

```
<a href="painel.php?logoff=true&token=<?php echo md5(session_id()); ?>">Sair</a>
```

---

```
if($logoff && $token == md5(session_id())){
    unset($_SESSION['userlogin']);
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ../painel');
}
```

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137086/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41517/101.

Comment: Um comentário rápido que eu poderia fazer para te dar uma luz seria dizer que o MD5 não tem como ser descriptografado por ser um hash, é teoricamente impossível. Porém, existe uma maneira de *deduzir* hashes através de conhecimento prévio, ou seja, se houver uma base de dados com milhões de MD5 hashes produzidos por strings aleatórias, é possível obter um "antes e depois" e assim então caso tenha sorte, encontrar o hash que você precisa na base de dados.

Comment: Isto é pra checar se quem esta pedindo o LOGOFF é a mesma pessoa? Tirando a parte de segurança sobre criptografias, a lógica do código não faz sentido e nem parece necessária.

Comment: Guilherme, sim, é pra isso. Mas pq não faz sentido? Imagina uma pessoa mal intencionada ficar mandando links de logoff pras pessoas por exemplo. Só um exemplo. Com esse modo não teria como.